# Can I pass a multi-line string to svn in PowerShell?

Tags: svn, powershell

I have the following line in a script:

`svn propset svn:externals $newExternals $path`

Now for the first time `$newExternals` is a multi-line string (there are several `svn:external` properties) and `svn` barks at me in a way that seems to indicate that it cannot deal with the argument.

***Can I not pass a multi-line string to a program I invoke in PowerShell?*** Or is that a problem with `svn` not being able to parse that? Or do I need quotes? (Didn't help, but I might have screwed up something else.)

---

If this doesn't work, then `svn` would also accept a file to read the stuff from:

`svn propset svn:externals -F externals.txt $path`

However, this seems to fail because `svn` expects `externals.txt` to be an ASCII file (or UTF-8, I'm not sure, but I don't think it's relevant here), while PowerShell by default writes UTF-16. So what's the canonical way to pipe something into an ASCII file?

---

As a side question: What's the canonical way to get a path to create a temporary file at?

Answer (score 2):

[io.path]::GetTempFileName() will return a temporary file name (including path)

Comment: Thanks! But do I really have to do that? (I.e., can I really not pass a multi-line argument?) Also, How do I write ASCII/UTF-8 to such a file?

Comment: I don't know about the multi-line argument thing, but that wouldn't be a powershell question, but a command-line issue.  As far as writing the content in a particular format, you would use set-content with the encoding parameter (possible values are Unknown, String, Unicode, Byte, BigEndianUnicode, UTF8, UTF7, Ascii)

Comment: Um. Do you perchance mean `out-file`, rather than `set-content`?

Comment: I didn't, but you could use that as well.

Comment: I couldn't find how to use `set-content` for this. It doesn't seem to have an encoding option. I used `out-file` now, and this works.

Comment: The -encoding parameter was added to set-content in v2

Comment: Mhmm. I thought I _am_ using PS2, and `gh sc` didn't reveal this. Oh well, I got it running. Thanks for sharing your wisdom with me! If not someone comes along shortly with an answer how to do this without a temp file, I'm going to have to accept yours.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not that familiar with `svn`, so excuse me if the following aren't relevant... but you can certainly pass multi-line strings into Powershell, or a Powershell invoked program (assuming the invoked program supports it).

[Here's one way to do it that I particularly like, from Technet Windows Powershell Tip of the Week](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692792.aspx).  (Powershell 'Here-Strings`).

[And here's another, from an SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3235993), though I have no idea if this will work with an invoked program... just that it works natively in PowerShell.

> Finally, strings (in all varieties) may also extend beyond a single line:

```
'Foo
bar'
```

If neither technique works, I'd say you've run into a limitation of `svn`.

Comment: Thanks. I do have a multi-line text in my script already, though, within that `$newExternals` variable. If it is common to pass this around, I suppose it's some unfortunate interaction with or limitation of `svn`, which I ran into.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, the users temporary folder can be found using the system variable TEMP or TMP.

```
[Batch]
echo %TEMP%
echo %TMP%

[Powershell]
echo $env.temp
echo $env.tmp
```

Comment: Thanks, but I knew that much. The problem is that there already might hang around and `externals.txt` — which I might be allowed to wipe or not, have permissions to write to or not. A better solution would be to create a unique file name.